# Get plain text from REST response

Tags: reactjs, rest, promise, fetch

I use fetch to get data from my REST service. Once the Response arrives, I want to get the error message, if any, and display it to the user (the user is mostly me).

```
fetch(address, attributes).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
            return {
                text: "Server not found!",
                status: "danger"
            };
        }
        return {
            text: response.text(),
            status: "danger"
        };
    }
    return {
        text: "Success!",
        status: "success"
    };
}
```

The `response.text()` part is the important one: My Backend sends a javax.rs Reponse with a String as entity, e.g. "Error". Here, I want to read it, but response.text() returns only a Promise object which only returns more Promise objects when resolved.

I also tried using `{"msg":"[error]"}` and then parse it here as `reponse.json().msg` instead, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Success test case
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
            return {
                text: "Server not found!",
                status: "danger"
            };
        }

        return response.text().then(text => {
            return {
                text: text,
                status: "danger"
            };
        })
    }
    return {
        text: "Success!",
        status: "success"
    };
}).then(resp => {
    console.log("result:", resp);
})

// Failure test case 404
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/Not_Exist").then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
            return {
                text: "Server not found!",
                status: "danger"
            };
        }

        return response.text().then(text => {
            return {
                text: text,
                status: "danger"
            };
        })
    }
    return {
        text: "Success!",
        status: "success"
    };
}).then(resp => {
    console.log("result:", resp);
})

// For testing Errors other then 404, i changed 404 error in the code because i couldn't get other HTTP Errors from placeholder api

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/Not_Exist").then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 999) {
            return {
                text: "Server not found!",
                status: "danger"
            };
        }

        return response.text().then(text => {
            return {
                text: text,
                status: "danger"
            };
        })
    }
    return {
        text: "Success!",
        status: "success"
    };
}).then(resp => {
    console.log("result:", resp);
})
```

Yes `text()` function returns [promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text). So one solution could be to use it this way:

```
fetch(address, attributes).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
            return {
                text: "Server not found!",
                status: "danger"
            };
        }

        return response.text().then(text => {
            return {
                text: text,
                status: "danger"
            };
        })
    }
    return {
        text: "Success!",
        status: "success"
    };
})
```

The `json()` function can be used in the same way:

```
response.json().then(json => {
    return {
        text: json.msg,
        status: "..."
    };
})
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me sadly; it appears that the then() only returns the array to the next then() instead of using the function's return. As such, I always get "Success!" even though the operation failed internally.

Comment: @Hathics oops i forgot to add `return`. I edited the answer, check out the test cases now.

Comment: Happy coding ;)